# how to print this loop pattern

Tags: java, logic

How to solve this pattern?
its looks like a wave for me.

```
input:4

1 8 9  16
2 7 10 15
3 6 11 14
4 5 12 13
```

i managed to pull out some correct numbers but i know its very far from solved.

Here is my code

```
//asume g is from input
 int g = 4;

      for(int x = 1; x <=g;x++){
      int d = x;
        for(int y = 1;y<=g;y++){
          System.out.print(d+" ");
          d = g*x-y;
        }
        System. out. println();
      }

output:

1 3 2 1 
2 7 6 5 
3 11 10 9 
4 15 14 13
```

Comment: my recommendation: create a two D array which you fill with the appropriate values. Only once that is done, you print them in the right order

Comment: with rows numbers from 0, it's respectively 1+row, 2*g-row, 2*g+1+row, 4*g-row

Comment: You should add two spaces to numbers less than 10 if the number at the end of the column is > 10. To resolve the wave output

Comment: just by that example it is hard to say how it is generated (could be row sum `34` (`30 + g`))

Comment: BTW for info your question has absolutely nothing to do with "design-patterns" tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @B. Go's comment, you can achieve this following code snippet:

**Code snippet**

```
int g = 4;
for (int row = 1; row <= g; row++) {
    for (int col = 1; col <= g; col++) {
        if (col%2 == 1) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", g*(col-1)+row);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", g*col-row+1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Console output**

```
 1  8  9 16 
 2  7 10 15 
 3  6 11 14 
 4  5 12 13
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I didnt expect a short code like that. Awesome!. By the way, how did you build your problem solving skills?

Comment: @Jerbx You're welcome! I The more important thing than coding is **observing**. If you observed the regulation such as writing answer as functions in mathematics, then it can be always transformed into code!

Answer (score 0):

Please find a basic solution, This is not a good approach.

But it will give the correct result.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static List<ArrayList<Integer>> pattern(int j) {
        List<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        boolean loopComp = true;
        int resultArrayIndex = 0;
        int toAddWithResultForAntiClock = j - 1;
        int resultToPut = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= j * j - 1; i++) {
            resultArrayIndex = i % j;
            if (resultArrayIndex == 0) {
                loopComp = !loopComp;
            }
            if (loopComp) {
                resultToPut = i + 1 + toAddWithResultForAntiClock;
                toAddWithResultForAntiClock = toAddWithResultForAntiClock - 2;
            } else {
                resultToPut = i + 1;
            }
            if (toAddWithResultForAntiClock == -(j + 1)) {
                toAddWithResultForAntiClock = j - 1;
            }
            try {
                result.get(resultArrayIndex);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
                result.add(a);
            }
            result.get(resultArrayIndex).add(resultToPut);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ArrayList<Integer>> result = pattern(4);
        for (ArrayList<Integer> arrayList : result) {
            System.out.println(arrayList);
        }
    }
}
```

It will print the result:

```
[1, 8, 9, 16]
[2, 7, 10, 15]
[3, 6, 11, 14]
[4, 5, 12, 13]
```

Comment: Yes and it works so its still a very nice answer. Thank you sir. I will analyze the code until i get the process on how it works